# Using MarkLogic: Is there a way to get the ".find" behavior in bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, json, marklogic

I'm trying to think of a way to store a string in a variable in order to use that string as a "path" to a JSON property so that I can update that property.

The idea is that I have a base document that someone would like to modify to see what the document looks like with certain properties changed.

So, my thought is that I can store an array that has objects that look like this:

```
                    {
                        "LineItem": {
                            "Path": "/LevelA1/LevelB1/PropertyA",
                            "Value": 12345
                        }
```

And I can even "path" to a specific object in an array, like this:

```
                    {
                        "LineItem": {
                            "Path": "/LevelA1/LevelB2/.[PropertyC3=\"ValueD3\"]/PropertyD4",
                            "Value": 12345
                        }
                    }
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the `.xpath` feature in MarkLogic to allow me to update a value at that path.

So, I'm trying to make an Object out of my document and updating the Object (because all I really have to do is return the updated Object in a Service, I'm not really writing it to the database).

My thought would be to use a dot notation string and iterate over the string separating it at the dots with a function like this:

```
function setDepth(obj, path, value) {
    var tags = path.split("."), len = tags.length - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        obj = obj[tags[i]];
    }
    obj[tags[len]] = value;
}
```

However, that only works when there's not an array where I have to `find` the appropriate object to update.

I haven't been able to figure out if there is bracket notation that gives you "where" functionality (aka ".find" in dot notation).

I can do this:
`updatedDoc.LevelA1.LevelB2.find(x => x["PropertyC3"] === "ValueD3").PropertyD4`
And this:
`copiedObject["LevelA1"]["LevelB2"].find(x => x["PropertyC3"] === "ValueD3")["PropertyD4"]`

But I just can't figure out whether there's a bracket notation that'll get me the `.find` functionality.  Because this breaks the `setDepth` function:
`'LevelA1.LevelB2.find(x => x["PropertyC3"] === "ValueD3").PropertyD4'` when passed as `path`.

So, if someone knows:

1. actually how to use ".xpath" to update an in-memory object in javascript (sjs) in MarkLogic
   or
2. how to do `find` functionality in bracket notation
   or
3. whether there's a better way to accomplish the same thing (loop through an array of "something" that processing information about specific properties within a large hierarchical JSON object that include arrays with those specific properties)

I'd appreciate it...

Ok, to provide an example, here is the "document":

```
{
    "envelope": {
        "headers": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "name": "MadeUp"
                }
            ]
        },
        "triples": [],
        "instance": {
            "Root": {
                "PropertyA1": {
                    "PropertyB1": 1,
                    "PropertyB2": 2
                },
                "PropertyA2": [
                    {
                        "PropertyB3": 3,
                        "PropertyB4": 4,
                        "PropertyB5": 5,
                        "PropertyB6": "ValueB1",
                        "PropertyA3": [
                            {
                                "PropertyC1": {
                                    "PropertyD1": 6,
                                    "PropertyD2": "ValueD1"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the equivalent "paths" - dot notation and xpath:

```
{
    "LineItems": [
        {
            "LineItem": {
                "Path": "envelope.instance.Root.PropertyA1.PropertyB1",
                "Xpath": "/envelope/instance/Root/PropertyA1/PropertyB1"
            }
        },
        {
            "LineItem": {
                "Path": "envelope.instance.Root.PropertyA1.PropertyB2",
                "Xpath": "/envelope/instance/Root/PropertyA1/PropertyB2"
            }
        },
        {
            "LineItem": {
                "Path": "envelope.instance.Root.PropertyA2.find(x => x.PropertyB6 === 'ValueB1').PropertyB3",
                "Xpath": "/envelope/instance/Root/PropertyA2/.[PropertyB6='ValueB1']/PropertyB3"
            }
        },
        {
            "LineItem": {
                "Path": "envelope.instance.Root.PropertyA2.find(x => x.PropertyB6 === 'ValueB1').PropertyB4",
                "Xpath": "/envelope/instance/Root/PropertyA2/.[PropertyB6='ValueB1']/PropertyB4"
            }
        },
        {
            "LineItem": {
                "Path": "envelope.instance.Root.PropertyA2.find(x => x.PropertyB6 === 'ValueB1').PropertyB5",
                "Xpath": "/envelope/instance/Root/PropertyA2/.[PropertyB6='ValueB1']/PropertyB5"
            }
        },
        {
            "LineItem": {
                "Path": "envelope.instance.Root.PropertyA2.find(x => x.PropertyB6 === 'ValueB1').PropertyA3.find(x => x.PropertyC1.PropertyD2 === 'ValueD1').PropertyC1.PropertyD1",
                "Xpath": "/envelope/instance/Root/PropertyA2/.[PropertyB6='ValueB1']/PropertyA3/PropertyC1[PropertyD2='ValueD1']/PropertyD1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So, is there a way to process the dot notation "string" in javascript or is there a bracket notation that does the equivalent (which is actually what the https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#set is doing?

Comment: The high-falutin concept you are describing is a [lens](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/ever-heard-of-lenses-a480bea08786) although that's probably overkill. Try [`_.set`](https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#set)

Comment: No, that doesn't work.  The simple example is relying on `[0]`.  I actually have to `find` the appropriate object to update:
```LevelA1.LevelB2.find(x => x["PropertyC3"] === "ValueD3").PropertyD4``` and that `set` breaks if I make that the `path`.
This is what the `pathArray` evaluates to:
```
[
"LevelA1", 
"LevelB2", 
"find(x => x", 
"\"PropertyC3\"", 
" === \"ValueD3\")", 
"PropertyD4"
]
```

Comment: I've re-opened the question, although I'm pretty sure you're not going to get an answer. XML is much more structured than JSON (which is how XPath can make such complex queries against it). There really isn't an equivalent for JSON (unless MarkLogic has some magic to do it, never used it), you are going to have to write a bunch of bespoke code to do it.

Comment: But that's only part of the question - the xpath part is an "option" I've tried.
I'm also trying "dot notation".  What I'm trying to do is to create a "string" I can use as a variable.  For "dot notation", it would be this:
```LevelA1.LevelB2.find(x => x["PropertyC3"] === "ValueD3").PropertyD4```
However, that doesn't work.  As far as I can tell, I have to use this:
```LevelA1.LevelB2[0].PropertyD4```, which is not ideal because it relies on the Object in the Array not moving around over time.

Answer (score 0):

One approach used with MarkLogic is to harness `xdmp.nodeReplace()`.  Yes, this does "write" a temporary document, and has a transaction.  However, understanding the internals of MarkLogic, the structure in question is in an in-memory stand. The nice thing about this approach is that the path in question is exactly the same for `doc.nodeReplace()` as it is for `node.xpath()`

We let Mark Logic do the heavy lifting and isolate what needs to be changed.

Approach:

- Write temp doc (in memory stand)
- Alter temporary doc (using xPath)
- Read changed doc
- Remove doc

  ```
   var doc = {
     foo:123,
     bar:{
       baz:[
     1,2,{buz:12}
     ]
   }
   }

   const tempUri = "temp-" + sem.uuidString()
   const path  = "/bar/baz[3]/buz"

   //insert
   xdmp.invokeFunction(function(){
     declareUpdate();
     xdmp.documentInsert(tempUri, doc);
   })

   //update via xPath
   xdmp.invokeFunction(function(){
     declareUpdate();
     var n = new NodeBuilder();
     newBuz = n.addNumber(19).toNode();
     xdmp.nodeReplace(cts.doc(tempUri).xpath(path), newBuz);
   })

   //read again
   var newDoc = xdmp.invokeFunction(function(){
     return cts.doc(tempUri)
   }).toObject()

   // cleanup
   xdmp.invokeFunction(function(){
     declareUpdate();
     return xdmp.documentDelete(tempUri)
   })


   newDoc
  ```

Original: (buz=12)

```
    {
      "foo": 123, 
      "bar": {
        "baz": [
          1, 
          2, 
          {"buz": 12}
        ]
      }
    }
```

Result: (buz is 19)

```
    {
      "foo": 123, 
      "bar": {
        "baz": [
          1, 
          2, 
          {"buz": 19}
        ]
      }
    }
```

The benefit above is that part of MarkLogic's universal index is that the path of all values is already indexed.

Could You do this all in memory?
Yes - Using recursion and testing each node and it's path. Larger docs and recursion/test per node would likely consume more time and resources.

Comment: Thanks David.  If there isn't a way to get "bracket notation" to replicate the xpath functionality of ```/LevelA1/LevelB2/.[PropertyC3=\"ValueD3\"]/PropertyD4```, I'll consider this temporary document solution.

Comment: @DavidSteiner - One thing I note is that You don't have an example of the document.   Upon visual inspection of the xPath expression above, I think the issue is that you have a dot (.) that is not needed.  I created a sample doc  and used this : `/LevelA1/LevelB2[PropertyC3=\"ValueD3\"]/PropertyD` against  examples of this:  `  {
    "LevelA1" : {
      "LevelB2": {
        "PropertyC3" : "ValueD3",
         "PropertyD" : "Example 2" 
      }
    }
  } ' structure (where PropertyC3 did not always match "ValueD3" and the expected items were updated and those not matching were skipped.

Comment: You would have to translate array/bracket/filter notation into an xPath expression on your own. If there are more questions, perhaps isolate the un-answered items from the list and re-open a specific question .  Also keep i mind that MarkLogic has a (new) community forum located here: https://community.progress.com/s/products/marklogic  - This is a good pace to have more open discussions that do not match the format of StackOverflow.

Comment: The dot is because the objects in the array of LevelB2 are un-named.  I transformed the names of the real Properties of my data to "LevelA1", "LevelB2", "PropertyC3" "ValueD3" and "PropertyD4".  My xpath works for my data.  I'm not worried about the xpath.
What I'm trying to figure out is whether there's an equivalent javascript dot/bracket notation because this would allow me to do everything in the script/code without writing using the xpath solution which "requires" writing a temporary document to the database.